# SQL search for string within string, excluding another string

Tags: sql, sql-server, search

I have an SQL field containing a large chunk of HTML. I'd like to identify any records where there is the string "http://" but it is not part of a string that is "http://www.example.com." Many of the records include "http://www.example.com" -- I am not looking to exclude those. Rather, to return them if there is an additional "http://" link that is not of the same format.

As an example, I would want to return these records:

- http://www.foo.com is a great site but http://www.example.com is not
- http://www.foo.com is a great site

but not this one:

- http://www.example.com is a great site

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what is and is not good?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE REPLACE(field, 'http://www.example.com', '') LIKE '%http://%'
```